# Trying to make an external api call then insert data in to mongo db and then render the resulting entry to the template

Tags: javascript, express

I am fairly new to web development and am having a difficult time getting this route right. I want the route to call out to API then insert the data from the api into my mongo db and then render that result to a handlebars template. Not getting the promises thing I guess. Code below:

The code runs the api call, gets back data and even inserts into db but will not render the template after(I originally had it rendering with the api response but I want to have an db id attached when it renders over to the template). I am sure it has something to do with the promises. I have tried with callbacks with no luck so tried with async/await functions and this doesn't seem to work either. Again I still have issues with multiple callbacks so I was trying something else.

The code runs the api call, gets back data and even inserts into db but will not render the template after(I originally had it rendering with the api response but I want to have an db id attached when it renders over to the template). I am sure it has something to do with the promises. I have tried with callbacks with no luck so tried with async/await functions and this doesn't seem to work either. Again I still have issues with multiple callbacks so I was trying something else.

```
async function getRecipeData(param) {
  let res = await axios.get("https://api.edamam.com/search?q=" + param + "&app_id=0abb0580&app_key=bc931d03c51359082244df2fa414c487");
  var dataArray = res.data.hits
  return (dataArray);
}

async function insertSearchedRecipes(resArray) {
  let response = await
  Recipe.create({
    name: resArray[i].recipe.label,
    image: resArray[i].recipe.image,
    url: resArray[i].recipe.url
  });
  return response;
};


router.get('/getRecipes/:ingredient', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/");
  var params = req.params.ingredient;
  console.log(params);

  let recipeFind = getRecipeData(params);

  recipeFind.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      var recipeFindCreate = insertSearchedRecipes(result);
    };

    recipeFindCreate.then(function (results) {
      console.log("HELLO")
      // console.log(results);
      res.render("recipeResults", {
        data: results
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an array from external api and for each element in the array do you need to call insertSearchedRecipes?

Answer (score 0):

Standard trap `async` / `await`. The values returned from the function defined as `async` ALWAYS you must obtain by `await` / `then`.

By calling `recipeFindCreate` you only wait for last one, rest are make async.

```js
let _ = [];
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   _.push(insertSearchedRecipes(result));
};
let results = await Promise.all(_);
```

As you refactorize the code, make sure that each variable is declared in a function.

```js
async function insertSearchedRecipes(resArray) {
  let response = await
  Recipe.create({
    name: resArray.recipe.label, //NOT: `resArray[i]`
    image: resArray.recipe.image,
    url: resArray.recipe.url
  });
  return response;
};
//and:
var recipeFindCreate = insertSearchedRecipes(result[i]); // not `result`
```

Also, take a look at the bulk / bath insert theme - adding a data series made in 1 operation.

BTW: try don't use `var` (global scope). Better use `let` / `const`